# PHP manipulating multiarray data

Tags: multidimensional-array

I have a problem. I don't know how to show the exactly data I want.

My array is like this:

```
$races[$numRace][$finalPosition]

$races[1][1] = array ('stephan','1:27,895');
$races[1][2] = array ('george', '1:29,075');
$races[1][3] = array ('peter',  '1:29,664');
$races[1][4] = array ('benson', '1:29,915');
$races[2][1] = array ('benson', '1:41,113');
$races[2][2] = array ('stephan','1:41,434');
$races[2][3] = array ('george', '1:43,654');

 foreach ($races as $v1) {
     foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
       foreach ($v2 as $v3) {
         echo "$v3\n";
     }
   }
 }
```

This one shows me every data of $race array.

My question is: How can I do for showing just results for race 2?

Important: We don't know how many runners have participated on each race (So, we need a "foreach").
I would like a result like this:

1. benson
2. stephan
3. george

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply iterate through only the relevant array. Based on your code your `foreach` should be:

```
foreach ($races[2] as $pos => $info){
     echo $pos.': '.$info[0];
}
```

I've hard-coded the value `2` in the code but you could easily use a variable (`foreach ($races[$raceNum]`).

If you don't already know, `=>` makes it possible for us to use both the key *and* the value as variables in our loop.

Comment: Thanks!!!

It's just exactly what I wanted!!
I didn't know I could manage a multiarray this way.

Comment: And my last question...
What if I want to list all winners, without knowing how many races has the array..?
Something like this: (I know it's wrong)
foreach ($races[][1] as $winner => $info){
     echo $winner.': '.$info[0];
}

Comment: @user3096769 Comments aren't good for code but something like this: `foreach ($races as $race){
     echo 'Winner: '.$race[1][0].' - '.$race[1][1];
}`